# How do i customize the "title" on the first page of Wiki Server 4 on OS X Server Mountain Lion?

Tags: osx-server, server.app

How do i customize the "title" on the first page of Wiki Server 4 on OS X Server Mountain Lion?

The title says "OS X Server" and i want it to say something else... How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok... i did some digging around... and struck gold.

The digging part is not for the "faint of heart" since the Terminal is your best friend and some coding knowledge is involved. Suffice to say my trip in Wiki Server 4 land led me through Ruby on Rails code.
I was surprised to find that i'm able to read ruby code, and i don't know Ruby at all.
After looking through Model Views and Controllers i figured out the solution was simpler than i anticipated.

*To modify the title on the first page you need to edit a .strings file.
You need to use the download version (not the mac app store app) of TextWrangler or some other editor that allows Authenticated Saves (save files as other users).
Make sure the Wiki service is off... the slider in the server app is off.*

The location of the file depends on your language locale that you use:

**/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/collabd/coreclient/locales/en.lproj**

where "en" can be either de, es, fr, it, ja, ko, nl, zh_CN, zh_TW depending on your wiki language.

- First()

  you need to right click on the file and "Get Info" and adjust the permissions temporarily for "Everyone" to "Read and Write".

Open the file in TextWrangler and find the key general.os_x_server and under it you can modify the string "OS X Server" to anything you want "My own company Wiki".

- Save()

  the file.
- Second()

  you need to right click on the file and "Get Info" and adjust the permissions temporarily for "Everyone" back to just "Read".
- Move()

  the slider in the Server App to On again for the wiki.

Enjoy!!!

Comment: You're awesome! I have been looking for this kind of solution for long time and never managed to pull off all the pieces together!

Comment: I've gone even further... you can even translate the entire thing to a new language. Disable stuff you don't need... etc. It's written in Ruby on Rails and Javacript, the source code is visible and you can go in and customize to your hearts content.
I don't know Ruby but it's so well written i actually enjoy hacking it, and learning a lot along the way.

Comment: Now you need to edit "_OSXServer in strings.js in Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/collabd/coreclientbase/locales/xx.lproj

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution:

Load the front page and 'View Source' in the web browser.

Save the source as /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/index.html

Edit index.html and change the title (also any additional meta tags).

The nice thing about this solution is that it still allows you to edit the content whilst customizing the headers. You could probably modify the tool bar as well by the looks of things.